# Extending Polygon to Another Polygon with Automation?

Tags: polygon, length, extend

I need to extend the polygons in blue to match the red polygons using automation, since there are thousands of these. It seems like a simple thing to do, but I have not found a suitable way to accomplish it.

[image]

Comment: What software and license level (if applicable) do you have at your disposal? What have you tried so far and what result did you get?

Comment: I am using ArcGIS Pro 10.4. I have tried Extend Line after converting the blue polygons to lines. I have also tried Snap and making a buffer so the red polygons intersect the blue, somehow I thought that would help. That white space with a cul de sac at the end is the roadway, I really just need the blue boundary to align with it. So the red polygons are just the space in between, I may or may not need those to achieve the ultimate goal of aligning those blue polygons...

Comment: This is indeed a tricky problem, to extend the lines to the cul-de-sac you would need to convert to line both feature classes and remove the common line, you could probably do that on the blue polygon with an erase on a buffer of the red polygon bounding line then clip the blue polygons line, buffer and erase the red polygon lines leaving both ends open, merge erased red & blue boundaries and use extend line http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000004000000 then feature to polygon with centroids of blue... some manual editing/checking will be needed.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications and don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.

Comment: I would hardly classify this as a "simple thing". It might *seem* simple for a human, but teaching a computer to do such a task will quickly expose complexities that approach an [NP-Complete problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness).

Comment: I like your link @Vince, I try to explain problems such as these more like https://xkcd.com/1425/ where although *to the eye* it seems simple but is very difficult to perform, or even adequately define, programatically.

Comment: Very nice question +1 vote to reopen. Just edit op adding ArcGis as a software of choice

Comment: There is no "ArcGIS Pro 10.4" - do you mean ArcGIS Pro 1.4?  Or maybe ArcMap 10.4?